# Get the title of a window without focusing it in Capybara / Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara

I have an app where a user could be looking at 2 possible browser windows / tabs.

If the user is in Window 2 and an event occurs in Window 1, I change the text of the title bar using JQuery Title Alert (https://github.com/heyman/jquery-titlealert) as a way of notifying them that something is going on in Window 1. The title text change will flash until Window 1 is focused.

All this works fine. However, I want to integration test this using capybara and selenium and I've hit an interesting problem. While I can switch between windows easily using something like:

```
      page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
```

I want to be able to get the Text of the **unfocused** window to test that it's text has changed. Does anyone know how to:

1. Get the titles of all the windows?
2. inspect properties of a window without switching to it / focusing on it?
3. any other way I could approach this problem?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` which has a `GetAllWindowTitles()`.  It should work in Ruby with the latest version 2.19. The following example in C# works.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
ISelenium browser = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.Url);
browser.Start();

// open a test page and some popup windows
browser.Open(@"Test.html"); // open the main page which has title 'My Main Window'
browser.Click("btnPop1"); // open a popup window with title 'My Popup 1'
browser.Click("btnPop2"); // open a popup window with title 'My Popup 2'

string[] titles = browser.GetAllWindowTitles();
foreach (string title in titles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(title);
}
browser.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is as expected:

```
My Main Window
My Popup 1
My Popup 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I can't seem to get a handle on WebDriverBackedSelenium or configure Selenium to use this from within a Rails project using Capybara even after upgrading to 2.19. I haven't seen any docs or Rails community docs about it as yet but I'll keep looking...

Comment: I don't know much about Rails or Capybara, but the reason I thought it would work is that [the Selenium release notes announced  `WebdriverBackedSelenium` can now be used in supported languages other than java](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/announcing-selenium-2-19-the-prancing-unicorn-release/).

Comment: You've definitely answered my question, now it's up to me to figure out the RoR implementation details. Thanks mate :)